# Haskell nested conditions

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue with a conditions where I have nested them. I'm new to Haskell and can't seem to find anything similar in my book or online. Here is an example of what I have:

```
someFunc s n r c e i
    | (i < s) 
    >>> | (e < s) = someFunc (changes go here conditions are met)
        | otherwise = createList (different set of conditions go here)
    | otherwise = n
```

The error being given is: "parse error on input `|'" at the point denoted in the code. How what is the best method of solving this?

Thanks and sorry for English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest guards that way, but it might be cleaner to separate it into two functions like so:

```haskell
someFunc s n r c e i
    | (i < s) = innerCondition s n r c e i
    | otherwise = n

innerCondition s n r c e i
    | (e < s) = someFunc (changes go here conditions are met)
    | otherwise = createList (different set of conditions go here)
```

Alternatively, you could keep it nested within the same function with an `if` statement:

```haskell
someFunc s n r c e i
    | (i < s) =
        if (e < s) then
            someFunc (changes go here conditions are met)
        else
            createList (different set of conditions go here)
    | otherwise = n
```

But I think the first example with separate guarded functions is cleaner.

Comment: Also note that if the inner condition is not exhaustive (e.g. does not end with `otherwise` or equivalent) then the program may crash without returning control to the outer conditions, as one might expect.